# Can I use both my refugee travel document and my national passport?

Tags: visas, passports, refugees, kenya

I hold refugee status in Germany and I have a refugee travel document under the 1951 convention but my national passport was returned to me back by the foreign office and it's still valid for 5 more years.

I want to visit Kenya. If I use the passport of my country of origin, I don't need a visa but with the blue passport (refugee document), I need to apply for a visa. However, in my blue passport, it states that I also hold a national passport.

Can I travel with both, or should I just destroy the national passport and use only the refugee travel document (blue passport)?

Comment: purposely destroying your passport, especially if you cannot go to your passport country to obtain a new one, is one of the stupidest things in life you can do!

Comment: @HankyPanky That's what OP wonders

Comment: Using your national passport may be seen as availing yourself of the protection of your country of origin, which would increase the risk that you would be forcibly returned there.  Don't do it without asking a lawyer who specializes in refugee law.

Comment: @phoog How will the Germans know, however, what document OP used in Kenya?

Comment: @Crazydre they might not.  But Kenya might decide to refuse entry.  Germany is not the only country that could return the traveler to his country of origin.

Comment: @phoog If you're refused entry, aren't you flown back to where you flew from?

Comment: @Crazydre not necessarily. If there's a question about whether you'll be accepted there, you'll be sent to your country of citizenship (for example, someone with a single-entry visa who's refused entry after leaving the visa-issuing country would not be returned to the point of origin). In this case, it seems *likely* that a traveler refused entry to Kenya would be returned to Germany after showing the refugee document, but there's no guarantee, and the probability of being sent home depend on Kenyan law and administrative practice, and possibly on the specific facts of the traveler's case.

Comment: @phoog, I think that should be an answer.

OP: For the reasons stated, you should _not_ travel on your national passport. Your asylum can be cancelled if you do. I do not, however, think it is a good idea to destroy it, as you may need it for documentation purposes later.

Comment: i would like to thank all of you guys for the gut advise